# Computer randomly reboots

Tags: hardware-failure

I dont use this particular computer often (sometimes go a month without use) but recently it keeps randomly rebooting, at ANY time.

Sometimes it will reboot multiple times before it even posts. Sometimes it reboots just after posting. Sometimes I can login (to XP) and it runs fine for a few minutes then just reboots. Occastionally, it doesnt reboot at all. One thing that is consistent, it doesnt turn OFF it, it always reboots.

It's really hard to test since I never know when its going to reboot. I tried moving the DIMMs to a different bank but that hasnt worked. The case fan and lights dont flicker/stop.

Whats the most likely component to be failing?

- MoBo: Gigabyte GA-EP43C
- PSU: EVO Labs 500w
- Memory: 2x2Gb DDR2
- CPU: Intel E7300
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX650

Comment: You will have to start replacing parts until the problem stops.

Comment: The above said is right can go with replacing or here just have a look at this http://www.registryrecycler.com/blog/2013/04/6-common-problems-of-pc-random-restarts/ which may assist you with some idea.

Comment: Turn off automatic reboot on blue screen, and check the Event Logs.  As-is this is too broad due to a lack of information.

Comment: There is no more information. There is no blue screen. It literally just reboots as though the power switch was flipped off/on. I tried checking the event logs; no errors or warnings.

Comment: I havent fixed my problem but I would agree its a duplicate. Now to figure out why my computer wont boot memtest from USB :(

Comment: Update: Tried removing DIMMs, one at a time, and all cards and DVD drive. Only graphics and hard drive connected. Problem still happening.